# Compute Module 3 BCM43364 WiFi via SDIO

Tags: wifi, driver, compute-module-3, broadcom

I have a [Murata 1FX](https://wireless.murata.com/eng/type-1fx.html) evaluation kit, and I'm attempting to use it to get WiFi working on a Compute Module 3 (with the CMIO board). It uses the Broadcom BCM43364 chipset, which is similar to what the RPi 3 uses and is supported in theory by the [brcmfmac driver](https://community.cypress.com/community/linux/blog/2017/12/22/fmac-supported-chipset-linux). I'm running an up-to-date Raspbian install.

The evaluation kit provides a full-sized SD card breakout (it's meant for i.MX6 boards which have a slot for it), so I've soldered wires to the pads and hooked them up to the CMIO board GPIO, and wired a resistor to pull the `WL_REG_ON` pin high. I've got it hooked up to GPIO 22-27 ([suggested by this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=98&t=88781)).

I've added this line to the `config.txt` file:

```
dtoverlay=sdio,poll_once=off
```

The device does seem to get detected during boot, this is `dmesg`:

```
$ dmesg | grep mmc1

[    1.963612] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (2 bytes)
[    2.040350] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    2.049793] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    2.060346] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
[    2.102246] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    2.112453] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (6 bytes)
[    2.339903] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
```

Trawling through the web, I came across [a bug report](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1643) that suggested a few things to try, so I've run this:

```
$ cd /sys/class/mmc_host/mmc1/mmc1:0001; find . -type f -exec grep -H . {} \;

./mmc1:0001:1/vendor:0x02d0
./mmc1:0001:1/device:0xa9a4
./mmc1:0001:1/power/runtime_suspended_time:0
grep: ./mmc1:0001:1/power/autosuspend_delay_ms: Input/output error
./mmc1:0001:1/power/runtime_active_time:0
./mmc1:0001:1/power/control:auto
./mmc1:0001:1/power/runtime_status:unsupported
./mmc1:0001:1/class:0x00
./mmc1:0001:1/modalias:sdio:c00v02D0dA9A4
./mmc1:0001:1/uevent:SDIO_CLASS=00
./mmc1:0001:1/uevent:SDIO_ID=02D0:A9A4
./mmc1:0001:1/uevent:MODALIAS=sdio:c00v02D0dA9A4
./power/runtime_suspended_time:0
grep: ./power/autosuspend_delay_ms: Input/output error
./power/runtime_active_time:0
./power/control:auto
./power/runtime_status:unsupported
./type:SDIO
./mmc1:0001:2/vendor:0x02d0
./mmc1:0001:2/device:0xa9a4
./mmc1:0001:2/power/runtime_suspended_time:0
grep: ./mmc1:0001:2/power/autosuspend_delay_ms: Input/output error
./mmc1:0001:2/power/runtime_active_time:0
./mmc1:0001:2/power/control:auto
./mmc1:0001:2/power/runtime_status:unsupported
./mmc1:0001:2/class:0x00
./mmc1:0001:2/modalias:sdio:c00v02D0dA9A4
./mmc1:0001:2/uevent:SDIO_CLASS=00
./mmc1:0001:2/uevent:SDIO_ID=02D0:A9A4
./mmc1:0001:2/uevent:MODALIAS=sdio:c00v02D0dA9A4
./uevent:MMC_TYPE=SDIO
./uevent:MMC_NAME=
./uevent:MODALIAS=mmc:block
```

The report suggests that it looks like there isn't a driver being loaded, and indeed `dmesg | grep brcmfmac` gives no results. I tried the following to get the MODALIAS to load the brcmfmac driver, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
$ grep sdio /lib/modules/`uname -r`/modules.alias

alias sdio:c*v02D0dA9A4* brcmfmac    <- added by me
alias sdio:c*v02D0d4373* brcmfmac
alias sdio:c*v02D0d4356* brcmfmac
alias sdio:c*v02D0d4354* brcmfmac
alias sdio:c*v02D0dA9BF* brcmfmac
alias sdio:c*v02D0d4345* brcmfmac
alias sdio:c*v02D0dA9A6* brcmfmac
alias sdio:c*v02D0d4339* brcmfmac
alias sdio:c*v02D0d4335* brcmfmac
alias sdio:c*v02D0dA962* brcmfmac
alias sdio:c*v02D0dA94D* brcmfmac
alias sdio:c*v02D0dA94C* brcmfmac
alias sdio:c*v02D0d4334* brcmfmac
alias sdio:c*v02D0d4330* brcmfmac
alias sdio:c*v02D0d4329* brcmfmac
alias sdio:c*v02D0d4324* brcmfmac
alias sdio:c*v02D0dA887* brcmfmac
```

It looks like I can't get the `brcmfmac` driver to load. What else should I be trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it working, by slightly modifying the Linux kernel for Raspbian. I had to modify it to have a definition for `SDIO_DEVICE_ID_BROADCOM_43364` with the value `0xA9A4`. I'm not really sure where this value is coming from, the [Cypress page](https://community.cypress.com/community/linux/blog/2017/12/22/fmac-supported-chipset-linux) says it should be `0xA9A6` - but nonetheless it makes the chip work and load the drivers.

Follow the [Kernel building guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md) to obtain the source and set up the build environment. Before compiling, modify the files `include/linux/mmc/sdio_ids.h` to have the line `#define SDIO_DEVICE_ID_BROADCOM_43364 0xa9a4` and `drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmfmac/bcmsdh.c` to have `BRCMF_SDIO_DEVICE(SDIO_DEVICE_ID_BROADCOM_43364)` in the appropriate location (see the diff below):

```
diff --git a/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmfmac/bcmsdh.c b/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmfmac/bcmsdh.c
index cd58732..b072fc9 100644
--- a/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmfmac/bcmsdh.c
+++ b/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmfmac/bcmsdh.c
@@ -1098,6 +1098,7 @@ static const struct sdio_device_id brcmf_sdmmc_ids[] = {
        BRCMF_SDIO_DEVICE(SDIO_DEVICE_ID_BROADCOM_43340),
        BRCMF_SDIO_DEVICE(SDIO_DEVICE_ID_BROADCOM_43341),
        BRCMF_SDIO_DEVICE(SDIO_DEVICE_ID_BROADCOM_43362),
+       BRCMF_SDIO_DEVICE(SDIO_DEVICE_ID_BROADCOM_43364),
        BRCMF_SDIO_DEVICE(SDIO_DEVICE_ID_BROADCOM_4335_4339),
        BRCMF_SDIO_DEVICE(SDIO_DEVICE_ID_BROADCOM_4339),
        BRCMF_SDIO_DEVICE(SDIO_DEVICE_ID_BROADCOM_43430),
diff --git a/include/linux/mmc/sdio_ids.h b/include/linux/mmc/sdio_ids.h
index cdd66a5..0a7abe8 100644
--- a/include/linux/mmc/sdio_ids.h
+++ b/include/linux/mmc/sdio_ids.h
@@ -35,6 +35,7 @@
 #define SDIO_DEVICE_ID_BROADCOM_4335_4339      0x4335
 #define SDIO_DEVICE_ID_BROADCOM_4339           0x4339
 #define SDIO_DEVICE_ID_BROADCOM_43362          0xa962
+#define SDIO_DEVICE_ID_BROADCOM_43364          0xa9a4
 #define SDIO_DEVICE_ID_BROADCOM_43430          0xa9a6
 #define SDIO_DEVICE_ID_BROADCOM_4345           0x4345
 #define SDIO_DEVICE_ID_BROADCOM_43455          0xa9bf
```

On my setup I have the `WL_REG_ON` pin pulled high, so the module is *not* reset when rebooting (i.e. no WiFi after a `sudo reboot`) - it only works on a hard power off and reboot. I'll change my layout to attach this pin to a GPIO, and control it that way.

---

I'll also go and check if there's anything like this in the upstream source that will eventually trickle down - if not I'll see about submitting this patch to upstream so that it doesn't always need to be done manually.

---

**Update**: The patch has been submitted upstream: https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10380047/

I suppose it'll trickle down to some future kernel version, although in the meantime the patch will still need to be manually applied.